# examples of sencha touch 2 are not working separately

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have separate the touchstyle folder and in my root directory. and place sdk folder inside the touchstyle folder. make changes in the index.html file to rout the development.js. and also make changes in the app.js to rouch the src folder. when i goes to the browser i only see the top toolbar with categories name and nothing else. what is i am missing. i want to grasp the sencha touch 2 by going through the examples .

and i am very confuse when i see that every person have a new method to accomplish his ideas.

please give me some suggestions. thanks

Now it's working i have made some modification in the separated touchstyle folder.

1. I pasted the folder sdk inside the touchstyle folder.
2. Open the index.html file and make change `<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="../../microloader/development.js"></script>` to `<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>`
3. Open app.json file and make change
   from `"path": "../../sencha-touch-debug.js"` to `"path": "sdk/sencha-touch-debug.js"`
4. Open app.js file and make change 
   from `'Ext': '../../src'` to `'Ext': 'sdk/src'`
5. Finally, copy the sencha-touch-debug.js file from sencha touch and paste it in the sdk folder.

open the browser it is working now.

i need some more tutorials if any body know please share with me.

Comment: to be exact, what do you want to do?

Comment: i want to see how the examples are work so i make them functional outside the sencha touch folder. first i have asked question and then answer the question. but i need help to work with sencha touch.

Comment: @WaheedUrRehman i have same issue , can you help me on it.

Comment: In my question i have answered my question please follow the instructions step wise you will able to get working your examples alone not inside the sencha zip folder.